# how to implement row grouping in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a React application and I want to implement grouping in the same way as the image. I think its something called row groping but when i research, its not the same thing. How can i implement this?

I am using XGrid. Should i write my own component to achieve this or there is simplier way to do that?

> react version "17.0.1"

[image]

Comment: Looks like row spanning its not yet implemented - check out [here](https://mui.com/pt/x/react-data-grid/rows/#row-spanning). Probably you will need to go with your own component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased MUI-DataGridPro to solve this issue.